# How to use ForEach conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello I have an issue about confirm to protocol 'Hashable'. It's really suck.
This is my model:

```
struct Page: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var thumbnail: String?
    var description: String
    var type: String
    var speechs: [String]
}

struct ExploreDataSource: Decodable, Hashable {   
    var title: String
    var data: [Page]
}
```

This is my `ForEach` code:

```
List {
    ForEach(self.VM.dataSource, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.title).bold().font(.system(size: 22.0))\
    }
}
```

Error:

> Type 'ExploreDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'. Do
>   you want to add protocol stubs? Type 'ExploreDataSource' does not
>   conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Comment: change id from \.self to some other property, then it won't require to make type hashable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `Page` struct does not conform to `Hashable` respectively `Equatable` and therefore `ExploreDataSource` cannot conform to `Hashable` either.

So my suggestion is to make your `Page` conform to `Hashable` as well.

```
struct Page: Decodable, Identifiable, Hashable {
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question. Please edit your answer. I''ll pick you the best

Comment: @KitKit Thanks for adding the `Page` code. I updated my answer and it should be feasible to just make `Page` conform to `Hashable`