# Swift UI 'For Each' requires that 'Platform' confirms to' hashable' error

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I have been reading up on the issue and I understand that it's an issue due to the same name being called twice but which of double callings would be changed to resolve the issue? I have a forEach to display the different rows and then two callings for platform, I have changed them but it didn't resolve anything, after reviewing a few stack over flows and a hacking with swift document, I get the issue but can't figure out the resolve within my case.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Platform {
    let name: String
    let image: String
}

let platforms = [
    Platform(name: "Paypal", image: "paypal-icon"),
    Platform(name: "eBay", image: "ebay-icon"),
    // Add other platforms here...
]

struct PlatformRow: View {
    let platform: Platform

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: paypalView()) {
            Image(platform.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4.75 ) - 1,
                       height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4.75 ) - 1)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(25)
        }
    }
}

struct gridView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(platforms, id: \.self) { platform in
                    PlatformRow(platform: platform)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(25)
    }
}

struct grid_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        gridView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ForEach conform to protocol 'Hashable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512177/how-to-use-foreach-conform-to-protocol-hashable)

Comment: Sightly, i wanted an explanation with my situation so I can fully understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `Hashable` conformance.

```
struct Platform: Hashable {
```

You will also benefit from `Identifiable`

```
struct Platform: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
```

SwiftUI is all about identity and knowing when something is different. It needs to determine when to reload the `body`.

Check out Demystify SwiftUI from #wwdc21
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Comment: what would be the best way to add a different navigation link for all the platforms?

Comment: @Flamee a `NavigationLink` is a part of what is called the "Presentation Layer" of the application. It should never be included in the "Model Layer" (that is where `Platform` is). `PlatformRow` is a good setup, views can adapt based on the model like you do there. but you re likely referring to `paypalView()` that should be adapted so that all `Platform`s can do whatever that shows/does based on the object itself, not based on the model holding a `view`, consider a `url` all platforms would have a platform specific `url` can be opened in the same manner (ex. name and icon)